# How can I auto increment the build number for a shared file in linux for c++ project

Tags: c++, linux, versioning, automake

I had a project which has some shared files. I need to maintain versions for all the shared files so I had used -version-info to get the version of the shared file as libeg.so.xx.yy.zz. But now, I want to add a new part which stores a new build number every time it is built.

For eg., when I built the project for the first time it gives libeg.so.1.0.0.1
the next time when I build the project it should create a shared file as libeg.so.1.0.0.2 in linux. So what can I do to get the required build number which will auto increment for every build. In this project I use automake to build c++ project.

I have used the below line in Makefile.am to get the version number after .so 
libeg_la_LDFLAGS =  -version-info 3:0:2

The output is libeg.so.1.2.0. But the required output is libeg.so.1.2.0.1 for the 1st build; libeg.so.1.2.0.2 for the 2nd build and so on.....
libeg.so.1.2.0.n for the nth build

Comment: Only you can choose how to do this. How do you build? What build system? Is it using technology you can use to store some incrementing count?

Comment: I build the project using automake in Linux. It's not using any technology which store incrementing count

Comment: You kick it off manually? No build server? No CI? Then you'll have to invent something! It could be as simple as a text file ... but only you can design this for yourself.